# How can I use LINQ to compare table values to values of properties of a list of objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

Given these classes,

```
public class Foo
{   
    ...  

    public IList<Bar> BarList{ get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    ...

    public int Property{ get; set; }
}
```

How can I juse LINQ to to create a query that filters for matches of the value of Property, when Property is a property of an object within a list?

i.e., I want to return all records where OtherTable's Property column has a value that matches ANY of the values of Property that exist in Foo.BarList. Something like

```
var result = db.MainTable.Include(m => m.OtherTable.Where(o => o.Property == {{Foo.BarList.Property}}) ...rest of query
```

Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear to me what `OtherTable` is. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I don't think `Include` does what you think it does. What is `MainTable`? Provide more actual datatypes / declarations that might compile. In general, `Where`/`Any` is exactly what you need.

Comment: Well the issue isn't with the tables, which is why I didn't supply details, it's with accessing Foo.BarList.Property so that I can use it as something to query against, which I don't know how to do. The main table is where most of the column data I need from the query resides, which I compare against in "rest of query". OtherTable is a related table in my database linked to it via a foreign key. @NetMage I thought that Include was for doing a Join.

Comment: Your question can't be answered without details. Your sample query is useless without details that explain e.g. the type of `m`, where `OtherTable` comes from and its type (not shown), how you expect to access a member property of a type (`Foo.Barlist.Property`), etc.